# Irreducible Linear Subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let k be an infinite field. Prove that any linear subspace of $A_k^n$ is irreducible.

My first question is, what would a linear subspace be? Is is a variety that is generated by linear equations?

Then, if this is the case, can we say that the ideals that generate them are prime, and therefore the varieties are irreducible (but maybe that needs algebraic closure?)?

Comment: A linear subspace is a variety defined by linear polynomials. Another (equivalent) way of thinking of this type of space is as a vector subspace of $\mathbb{A}^n\simeq k^n$. For your problem, show that a linear subspace is isomorphic to an affine space (think linear algebra).

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be a linear subspace with $dim_k(L)=d$. With a linear change of coordinate we can suppose $L$ is $\langle x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-d}\rangle$. Let $f:A^d_k\to A^n_k$, $f(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-d},\dotsc,x_n) = (0,\dotsc,0,x_{n-d+1},\dotsc,x_n)$. $f$ is clearly surjective.

$A^d_k$ is irreducible, because $\langle 0\rangle$ is prime ideal of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_{d}]$ (is domain).

**Lemma**. If $f$ is a polynomial morphism is continuos and image of irreducible sets are irreducible.

*Proof*. It's easy to see if $W$ is algebraic then $f^{-1}(W)$ is algebraic too. Now, suppose $W$ is irreducible and $f(W)$ isn't and get contradiction.

So $f(A^d_k)=L$ is irreducible.